# Android Eclipse debugging source not found

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I looked already a lot for a solution for my problem and found similar items - but unfortunately I could not get round with that all to solve my problem. Here is what messes me up:
My small project is with a button and an onClickListener on it.

```
package com.example.wbbtn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button wb1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        wb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        wb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint at `wb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);`

When I start the debugging with my tablet already set to the debugging mode and connected to the PC and hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> key I get the message that a source is not found.

I've made a screen shot to make things a bit more clear but I was told to have at least 10 reputations to post a pic. Okay - sorry !

Hello - sorry for this late response. Okay here are the links to the screen shots - hope it works:

[a) source not found](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/j8ektis0ecn6pcm/qrG_JIrRlE)

[b) Break point](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/jzyr8rmlmc16usn/90AzajZQdY)

Comment: Is that `Button` in `activity_main.xml`?. If yes then Post logcat error.

Comment: Post a link to the image in a supported format (jpg or png), and someone else will embed it in the question for you. Or wait for one more upvote. :)

Comment: are you using eclipse Juno? Its known to have these key binding issues. Also sometimes the debugger stops on a line (which might be in some library jar) when you've hit an exception but here that's unlikely the case.

Comment: Hi Uday - sorry I have to say I do not know how to find out which exactly version I am using with the adt bundle I downloaded. Under the help I found this here for the Eclipse platform info:
Eclipse Platform

Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
Build id: M20130204-1200

Comment: Oh - I just found out that the version 4.2 is corresponding to Juno - right?